# MySQL find only different in 2 table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 table in mysql. table1 and table2.

In table1 is number, email and phone number.
In table 2 same, but sometime different email or phone number.
i want to list of records where number is same and email or phone number different.
sometime both email and phone number is different.
tnx.

Comment: what is `number` and what is `phone number`

Comment: number is social security number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *join* your tables, then filter accordingly:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table1 JOIN table2 USING (number)
WHERE  table1.email <> table2.email
    OR table1.phonenumber <> table2.phonenumber
```

Comment: how i can see records in wich tables is?

Comment: @BeQaNikolashvili: Well the resultset's column metadata contains that information—how you access that depends on which API you're using?  Else you can explicitly list columns in the select list and provide different aliases to those from each table, e.g. `SELECT table1.email AS email_1, ...`.